# Add condition for smart-app-banner?

Tags: web, smartbanner

i'm using [smart-app-banner](https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner) for site. How i can add some condition for showing this banner? For example, user entered on our site but did not do any things with banner(close or install), that is why if he well return on our site next time, we must show this banner for him only after three days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this alternative to the solution you are currently using as it states: "When a customer visits your site, Desktop users are sent an SMS with a link to download your app. Mobile users are automatically directed to the appropriate app store."

https://github.com/ombori/app-banner